# What Adobe Acrobat alternatives have PDF signing features

Tags: pdf

We use Adobe Acrobat at work for creating signed PDF documents. Currently run Adobe Acrobat 6 Professional to sign these documents. Acrobat Reader will not sign PDFs. Is there any non acrobat product that can:

1. Sign PDFs
2. Add signature fields to PDFs.

The first is more important than the second since I sign PDFs more than I insert signature fields in PDFs.

Answer (score 2):

[OpenSignPdf](http://opensignature.sourceforge.net/english.php) is an open source project for the digital signature of PDF documents.

I'm not sure it this is a good idea, but there is
experimental [online PDF signing](http://opensignature.sourceforge.net/OpenSignPDFApplet.php) service.

Comment: Ludwig,

I'm looking for something that can sign PDF forms in particur places, not to sign a document as authentic. That does look interesting though.

Answer (score 2):

[pdfMachine pro](http://pdfmachine.com/genp/pdfmachine_signer.html) does digital signatures. They will also sell you a certificate if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried foxit [reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/reader/) and [creator](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/creator/)?

Comment: when posting Software recommendations (and it happens to be on topic), try to stick to a format as suggested in [this meta thread](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5329)

Comment: Foxit Reader 7.3 (portable) has a (digital) signing feature in the menu PROTECT / Sign&Certify...

Answer (score 1):

[jpdftweak](http://jpdftweak.sourceforge.net), although I never tested signing with it.

If you want to do it from a program, look at [iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText).

Answer (score 0):

You have also [Portable Signer](http://portablesigner.sourceforge.net/) that does PDF signing, and is multi platform.
It is based on the iText library.